# How Do I Activate the Cottage Blueprint?

Tags: harvest-moon-3d-a-new-beginning

This is what I have done so far:

Town Restoration Plans #1 & #2 completed.
Restaurant is built; music found and played successfully.
Clinic is built; I got no message or music for this build... (It was storming, but I went back to talk to Aaron and Alice and they just spoke their normal phrases when I came back during a normal day.)
I have shipped over 200,000G.
And I have 2 adult sheep (even though I only needed one for the plan, I wanted more for the wool.)
The Garden Festival was activated.
It is currently Fall 2 of Year 1.
I have 2 sheep, 1 cow, and 2 chickens.

I have plenty of beehives and mushroom logs. I don't know what I haven't done to get this blueprint to become available, but its not showing up at all. Does anyone have any suggestions?